# Code NetConnection.Connect.SSLHandshakeFailed in my RED5 server

Tags: actionscript-3, ssl, red5, netconnection, rtmps

I have an AS3 flash published with Flash Professional CC and published for Flash Player13.

The problem is: When I create a NetConnection to my RTMP Server (RED5 v1.1) I Have obtained th following error message: NetConnection.Connect.SSLHandshakeFailed.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
nc = new NetConnection();
nc.objectEncoding = ObjectEncoding.AMF3;
nc.client = this;
nc.proxyType = "best";
nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netSAServerRTMPStatus);
nc.connect("rtmps://myappserver.mydomain.com/myApp", myChannel);
private function netSAServerRTMPStatus(event:NetStatusEvent):void
{
     trace(event.info.code);
}
```

If I don't set the proxyType or I set it to any other option, the connection is never established, but if I set it to "best", I can create the connection sometimes, but not always.

In my server i have a SSL certificate signed by Geo Trust Inc and it's Common Name (CN) = *.mydomain.com

Can anyone help me please? I can give more information if it's needed.

Best regards,
Pimager

Answer (score 0):

You can enable ssl debug to get more details when it fails; add this entry to your JAVA_OPTS:

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl
```

You will then see entries like this in your log:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Client requested protocol TLSv1 not enabled or not supported
```

and / or

```
Exception caught on session: 1 id: EPP7XKEM0XUWC javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake failed.
```

In the case shown, TLSv1 was requested by the client and was rejected.

**Update**

Another thing you can test out, is enabling legacy stuff via parameter in your red5.sh; add these to your JAVA_OPTS:

```
-Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true -Dsun.security.ssl.allowLegacyHelloMessages=true
```

You can find information about these parameters [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/tlsreadme2-176330.html).